# Algebraic transformation using Logical Equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Exercise :

[Algebriac Transformation Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPhFS.png)

> Algebraically transform $$\lnot\forall x~(P(x)\land Q(y)\implies\exists z~R(z))$$ to $$\exists x~\forall z~(P(x)\land Q(y)\land\lnot R(z))$$
>
> Justify each attempt with one or more laws.

my attempts :

I've made many attempts, but I've struggled with separating the first z from ∃zR(z). I've been using DeMorgan's law for Quantifiers to convert between ∃ and ∀, but when trying to use the commutative law at the end, I always seem to be backwards with my ANDs and ORs. After a few hours of attempts, I'm out of ideas.

One of my attempts

> ¬∀x(P(x)∧Q(y))⟹∃zR(z)
>
> ∃x¬(P(x)∧Q(y))∨∃zR(z)
>
> ∃x¬(P(x)∧Q(y))∨∃zR(z)
>
> ∃x(∃zR(z)∨¬(P(x)∧Q(y)))
>
> ∃x(¬∀z¬R(z))∧¬(P(x)∧Q(y))
>
> ∃x(¬∀z¬R(z))∧(¬P(x)∨¬Q(y))

But from here I was lost.

Comment: Please actually *show* what attempts you have made, don't just tell.  Although it sounds like you are taking the correct approach, we cannot see where you are going awry.

Comment: Also ensure you are reading that first statement with the entire conditional *inside* the scope of the universal.$$\lnot\forall x~\color{red}{\big(}(P(x)\land Q(y))\to\exists z~R(z)\color{red}{\big)}$$

Comment: That is the right way the image has it , @GrahamKemp , OP made mistakes while writing & typing.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been using DeMorgan's law for Quantifiers to convert between ∃ and ∀,

That is a very good start.   You should not go wrong, *if* you are reading that first statement with the entire conditional *inside* the scope of the universal quantifier.

$${\lnot\forall x~\color{red}{\big(}(P(x)\land Q(y))\to\exists z~R(z)\color{red}{\big)}\\\exists x~\lnot\big((P(x)\land Q(y))\to\exists z~R(z)\big)\\\vdots}$$

Comment: That made all the difference. How do you know to read it all inside the scope of the universal quantifier?

Comment: It seems you did not read the Image right , @TateMcCauley , It is given with the right brackets